# How do you do construct a proof in type theory?

Tags: proof-writing, type-theory

I am reading about Type Theory and trying to understand how proofs work. The idea seems like, to prove something, you build up the type using the semantic construction rules. So I want to prove that 2 is even. My idea is to use the types by showing that 2 is of the type 'even' like this:

```
zero: nat
succ: nat -> nat
double: nat -> even
double(succ(x)) = succ(succ(double(x)))
```

(with 'succ' standing for successive number). So I start with

```
double(succ(zero)) : even
```

which using the last rule becomes

```
succ(succ(zero)) : even
```

Which seems to be a proof that two is even?? (Or is it). And how would one go about constructing a proof for example that a+b=b+a ? Presumably one would need to show that a+b has a 'dependent type' b+a. Whatever that means.

However I think I must be wrong since it says on Wikipedia that an element can be of only one type. So how can 2 be both of type 'nat' (natural numbers) and of type 'even'?

Comment: Maybe you can see some textbook: Rob Nederpelt & Herman Geuvers, [Type Theory and Formal Proof : An Introduction (Cambridge University Press, 2014)](https://books.google.it/books?id=orsrBQAAQBAJ&pg=PA305).

Comment: How do you define 'even'?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is in how you choose to define `even`. To do this you must specify how to construct terms of type `even`. Three ways of doing this would be

1. Define `even` as a subtype of `nat` by first defining `double : nat -> nat` and then specifying that the introduction rule is precisely the doubling function: $\vdash$ `double : nat -> even`. In this case, anything in the image of `double` is even *by definition*.
2. Define `even` as a subtype of `nat` inductively by specifying two introduction rules: $\vdash$ `zero : even` and `n : even` $\vdash $ `succ(succ(n)) : even`, in which case an even number is of type `even` *by definition*. (*Note: this is essentially equivalent to (1) above*)
3. Define `even` as the dependent sigma type
   $$\Sigma_{n : \texttt{nat}}\Sigma_{k : \texttt{nat}} (k + k = n)$$
   in which case an even number `n` is a triple `(n,k,p)` where `p` is a proof that `2*k = n`. Note however that for this definition to be the "right" definition we need to make sure that any even number has a unique witness `(k, p)` of it being even. This is only the case if `p` is unique, that is our type theory must satisfy the [Uniqueness of Identity Proofs](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/axiom+UIP) property. In your example, a proof that two is even would be the triple

   ```
   ( succ(succ(zero)), succ(zero), refl(succ(succ(zero))) ) : even.
   ```

   Note that this only works for *fixed constants* $n,k$ because we need $k+k$ to *evaluate* to $n$.

Now if you want to prove something more general about arbitrary numbers, as in your example $n+m = m+n$, you need to use the proof term for the induction rule for `nat`:

```
   nat_ind : (P : nat -> Prop) -> P(zero) -> 
              (forall (n : nat) (P(n) -> P(succ n))) -> (forall (n : nat) P(n))
```

where `forall` is the dependent product.

Comment: Type theory is very very hard.

Comment: @zooby Type theory can be very tricky, especially with equality. I would suggest learning type theory in a proof assistant, for example with Coq or Agda.